# Aplicacion se muere cuando un Thread entra suspend

Tags: android

Tengo un error cuando el `miHilo.suspend();`, mi aplicación se cierra y me muestra este error en la consola.

> 11-14 10:50:38.088 2390-2536/com.example.root.juegopuchale
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1788
>                                                                                 Process: com.example.root.juegopuchale, PID: 2390
>                                                                                 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.suspend(Thread.java:1061)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método **[suspend()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend())** es obsoleto, puedes encontrar referencias en la documentación android hacia este articulo:  **[Porque Thread.stop, Thread.suspend, 
Thread.resume y Runtime.runFinalizersOnExit son obsoletos? (inglés)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)** :

Puedes evitar el uso de `Thread.suspend()` y `Thread.resume()`  mediante:

```
public synchronized void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    e.consume();

    threadSuspended = !threadSuspended;

    if (!threadSuspended)
        notify();
}
```

Y agregando el siguiente código al "bucle de ejecución":

```
            synchronized(this) {
                while (threadSuspended)
                    wait();
            }
```

---

En realidad no puedes reiniciar un Thread (suspend > start), lo que se tiene que realizar es crear una nueva instancia .

```
Thread thread = new Thread();
thread.start();
```

Comment: Gracias, aplique la idea pero de una forma diferente, inclui un if donde uso, fuera verdadero, realizara las correspondientes acciones, y si era falso, no hiciera nada